# Inner Class object inside outer class

Tags: inner-classes

```
class Outer
{
    int outer_x = 100;
    
    void test()
    {
        Inner inner = new Inner();
        System.out.println(inner.i);
        inner.display();
    }
    
    class Inner
    {
        int i = 12;
        void display()
        {
            System.out.println("outer_x : " + outer_x);
        }
    }
    
    
    Inner inneri = new Inner();
    {
    inneri.display() ;
    System.out.println(inneri.i);        // This runs with no compile error
    }
    
    //System.out.println(inneri.i);      // This gives compile error
    }
class NestedClass
{   
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Outer outer = new Outer();
        outer.test();
    }
}
```

I have made an Inner class object inneri, in class Outer. If I run it inside a block, it runs fine, but it shows compile error outside the block. Why? Also why it is running inside the block without any Outer object?